# can't open file ,mystate for datafile2 =2

Tags: c++

When I debug this I can see it opens datafile1 , it reads the firstline and 
in the logfile I get roma-3-4.log

It change to c:/temp/roma-3-4.log but when I want to open it , it fails. I have check that the _Mystate = 2 .
What is the meaning of that

Thanks

in the transfersubs.cfg there is this
roma-3-4.log

**** In the directory c:/temp/ I have the following file
roma-3-4.log

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;



int main()
{


  string input;
  string logfile;
  string errorfile;

  short logfilesize1;


   fstream dataFile1("c:/temp/transfersubs.cfg", ios::in);

  if (dataFile1)
  {
  getline(dataFile1, input, '$');
  logfile=input;
  logfilesize1=input.size();
  errorfile=input;
  errorfile[logfilesize1-4]='e';
  errorfile[logfilesize1-3]='r';
  errorfile[logfilesize1-2]='r';

  logfile="C:/Temp/"+logfile;

  fstream dataFile2( logfile, ios::in);

  if (dataFile2)
  {

dataFile2.close();
  }
   else
  {
    cout << "ERROR: Cannot open logfile.\n";
   }





    dataFile1.close();
  }
     else
  {
      cout << "ERROR: Cannot open file.\n";
  }
      system("Pause");
     return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your getline doesn't bother looking the newline but only for a $. You didn't post the file you are reading from, but check to ensure it has a $ at the end of the file name otherwise it will fetch the entire file.

Comment: I added the following instructions : if (logfile != "c:/temp/roma-3-4.log" )

{
logfilesize1=1;
}
else
{
logfilesize1=0;

}  and logfile is not equal , must be something extra that is causing the problem

Comment: found it had to remove the \n value from the string

Comment: Good to hear. It's like I said, it will search for the next $, so if it doesn't include one but you have a newline after it, it will include it. If you add anything more to the file, that will also get added as well.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that unless you put a \n or endl after writing to the file using ofstream, ifstream won't be able to read anything from the file. In fact, adding a space after whatever you've written into file won't help either.

So always add a newline right after whatever it is that you've written to file using ofstream.